# Checking for duplicates across all cells

Tags: excel, vba

How do I code this in the most simplest way?

If let's say `Range("A1").value = "Thursday"`

Check for duplicates on all the cells which has value in them (B1, C1, D1,...)

If a duplicate is found, select 3 cells below each of those cells `Range("B2:B4")` and so on...

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to check for duplicates:

Using a WorksheetFunction

> =COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1

[image]

Using the VBA

```
Dim Target As Range
Dim r As Range

Set Target = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each r In Target
    r.Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Target, r.Value) > 1
Next
```

If you want to remove duplicates in the first column of the range

> Target.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

If you wanted to expand your range to include Columns B and C

> Set Target = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)

Remove duplicates in the first and third columns

> Target.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlNo

Remove rows that contain the duplicates

> Target.EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlNo

Comment: What are you doing if the text is more than 255 characters ?

Comment: @MeLine I just test it and RemoveDuplicates worked as expected on a single column filled with 300 character strings

Answer (score 0):

Below code identifies duplicate value in a column and highlight with red. Hope this might be of some help.

```
  iLastRow = Cells(chosenExcelSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Determine the last row to look at     
    Set rangeLocation = Range("A1:A" & iLastRow) 'Range can be updated as per your need

    'Checking if duplicate values exists in same column
        For Each myCell In rangeLocation
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rangeLocation, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
                myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3'Highlight with red Color
            Else
                myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2'Retain white Color
            End If
        Next
```